# Forgotten iOS Restrictions Password/Passcode

Tags: ios, password, parental-controls

My dad put restrictions on my phone. He put it for many things that he didn't even know about. For example, downloading and deleting apps and Safari. So now that I want to do different things on my phone, **I can't because my dad forgot the password.**

Is there a way that I could take off the restrictions without deleting all of my things? If that isn't possible, then how can I restore my phone so the restrictions could come off? I heard that you can use find my iPhone someway so I could take off the restrictions but I'm not sure and I don't want to do the wrong thing.

Comment: how do we know you have your dads permission to crack the passwords he set.

Comment: I have permission to. I asked him for it and he forgot. Thats why Im trying to find out ways to take them off.

Comment: @user81284 How are the actual steps that would need to be taken differ from trying to get around the permissions? As they are the same then the only way is if the Apple system is broken

Answer (score 6):

There's a tool that can recover the restrictions passcode from a device backup, called [Pinfinder](https://pinfinder.net/). Follow the [macOS instructions](https://pinfinder.net/mac.html) and download the tool which is a command line binary and it will recover your pin.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this without restoring the device. You won't break the hardware, but you will lose all your photos and music and apps and data from the apps - so be sure to connect to iTunes or save your photos and anything you can't lose to another place like a computer or a cloud service.

Quoting this Apple KB article titled ["iOS: Understanding Restrictions (parental controls)"](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213)

> If you lose or forget your Restrictions passcode, you will need to [perform a factory restore](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) to remove it.
>   .
>   .
>   Last Modified: Mar 25, 2014

The find my iPhone restriction is that if your iCloud account has the device locked, you will need to enter your iCloud password before the restore starts. This password is different from the PIN code that was entered when the parental controls were set up the first time.

If you really can't afford to lose the apps - you could have your parent write down on a piece of paper the pin codes they might choose now and then try entering them one by one to see if you can recall it. That is the best way to unlock, but you will soon run out of time to guess and entering / breaking that restriction by brute force isn't something that's viable.

Comment: MK - forgive the large edit - I wanted to address some other aspects of the OP's question since it's a good question in need of some edits. Feel free to revert my edit if you don't find it welcome or if it needs more work.

Comment: Okay so you suggest me to just restore it? And before I restore it it's going to ask me to put in my iCloud password?

Comment: @bmike, no problem with the large edit - it does have some useful information. I'll make additional edits if necessary.

Comment: @user81284 yes, you will need your iCloud password to restore any of the applications you have installed and your settings stored in the cloud.

Comment: This answer is (now) wrong as the passcode can acquired from an unencrypted iTunes backup, see Dag Høidahl's answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is a file that you can edit to change the Restrictions Passcode to anything you want.

First read the instructions at the following URL to help you understand the issues and reset process.

http://www.techbout.com/reset-restrictions-passcode-iphone-ipad-ipod-8365/

Download and install the following utility:  iBotBackup

Do a complete backup using iTunes.  Do not encrypt the backup.

Then in iBotBackup, open the file "com.apple.springboard.plist" under 
\SystemFiles\HomeDomain\Library\Preferences.  You can edit it in the XML editor, or copy and paste the text into TextEdit on the Mac and make the following changes.

1) Find all keys that begin with the string "SPParentalControl".   I grouped them together to make it easier to find them next time.

2) Replace the following keys to have the following text values.

```
<key>SBParentalControlsBlocked</key>
<false/>
<key>SBParentalControlsBlockTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate</key>
<real>504390922.912126</real>
<key>SBParentalControlsEnabled</key>
<false/>
<key>SBParentalControlsFailedAttempts</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>SBParentalControlsMCContentRestrictions</key>
<dict>
  <key>countryCode</key>
  <string>us</string>
</dict>
<key>SBParentalControlPIN</key>
<string>1234</string>
```

Before letting iBotBackup reboot the iPad, I also deleted the following key entirely, just for good measure, since it appeared to contain the lockout time interval:
    SBParentalControlsBlockTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    504390922.912126

15. Select Restore options
    You will now be asked to select from the following 3 restore options:
    a) Reboot device after restore
    b) Don’t Copy backup
    c) Remove items from device that will not be restored
    From these 3 options make sure that you select the first 2 options and uncheck the third option.

Then use iBotBackup to Restore this file back to your iPad / IOS device.

Your iPad will reboot.  Go to Restrictions again, and enter your new PIN of 1234.  You may need to enter the new pin more than once.

This worked for me !!   It also taught me a few more things about Apple IOS configuration.

The following URL was also somewhat helpful in understanding what keys to change:    https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2667637?start=105&tstart=0

Answer (score -5):

Just go  to Restrictions or Accessibility..idk..either way, get to Clear Browser Data and restrictions will be off.

Comment: That would be rather surprising. Can you describe in more detail what you have in mind here?

Comment: If it were that easy, what would be the point?