# How can I disable the iPhone Restrictions code?

Tags: icloud, iphone

I have forgotten my Restrictions passcode.

Is there a way that I can change it without resetting the iPhone? I have tried updating it and have contacted Technical Support, but they suggested that I back up my files to iCloud and restore to factory settings.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to remove the Restrictions passcode without restoring the device in iTunes or from the device. However, you can save your data by backing it up to iCloud or iTunes and restoring all content to the device after it has been restored.

Comment: I think that's the only way so I'll just do that. Thanx

Comment: The `Pinfinder` app can find the password, as shown on the other Question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/224327/19829

Answer (score 3):

Per Apple's [support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304):

> If you lose or forget your Restrictions passcode, you'll need to erase
>   your device and then set it up as a new device to remove the passcode.
>   Restoring the device won't remove the passcode.

Comment: What Apple fails to mention in the support doc is that if you have restrictions enabled--and you've forgotten your restrictions passcode--you can't erase your phone...and round and round and round we go.  In this situation the only real way is to remember or recover your restrictions passcode.

Answer (score -1):

You could ask the Apple Store employees to give you a new iPhone, or you could ask them to attempt entering your Restrictions passcode on your device.

Hope that works!